# Is there a way to access the iteration number in replicate()?

Tags: r, radix, apply, replicate

Is there some way to access the current replication number in the `replicate` function so I can use it as a variable in the repeated evaluation? For example in this trivial example I'd like to use the current replication number to generate a list of variable length vectors of the current replication number. For example, `x` below would represent the current replicate:

```
replicate( 3 , rep( x , sample.int(5,1) ) )
```

I know this trivial example is easy to do with `lapply`

```
lapply( 1:3 , function(x) rep( x , sample.int(5,1) ) )
```

But can you access the replication counter in `replicate`?

Comment: `replicate` just calls `sapply` which in turn runs `lapply`. It's a convenience function. So my guess is it's not meant for that.

Comment: ...and I think your best bet is to just `(l|s)apply` over `1:n` as you have done. I'm not sure why that would be problematic.

Comment: ... or just write a `for` loop.  There's no time penalty and it may be easier for you to manipulate the index variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, at least not in a supported, user-friendly way. As Arun put it:

```
> replicate
function (n, expr, simplify = "array") 
sapply(integer(n), eval.parent(substitute(function(...) expr)), 
    simplify = simplify)
...

> sapply
function (X, FUN, ..., simplify = TRUE, USE.NAMES = TRUE) 
{
    FUN <- match.fun(FUN)
    answer <- lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...)
    ...
```

Now this is what `sapply` sees if you pass `3`:

```
> integer(3)
[1] 0 0 0
```

Why don't you write your own version of `replicate` to use as a shortcut?

Comment: Thanks. I might just take you up on that, or stick to `lapply`!

Comment: Did anyone do that? Update?